# Como testar exceções em java usando spring e a lib Junit 5?

Tags: java, spring, exceção, testes-de-unidade, junit

Estou em dúvida de como testar minhas excessões em java usando os próprios recursos do Spring Framework.

Estou testando uma classe chamada `UsuarioValidator.java` e nela tenho um método chamado `naoPodeInserir(CriaUsuarioDto dto)`. Eu tenho várias validações dentro deste método pertirnentes a regras de negócios para inserção de um usuário no banco. Veja um dos meus métodos:

```
public void isNaoPodeIncluir(@NotNull CriaUsuarioDto model) {
        if (model.apelido == null || model.apelido.isEmpty()) {
            throw new BadRequestException("O usuário precisa de um apelido");
        }
        (...)

}
```

Cada uma das entradas que vão contra essas regras, ele emite uma exception chamada BadRequestException. Uma classe que eu criei extendendo RuntimeException. Veja ela implementada:

```
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
public class BadRequestException extends RuntimeException {

    public BadRequestException(String message) {
        super(message);
    }

}
```

E minha classe de teste, eu tenho as seguintes propriedades... Ambas gerenciadas através de uma injeção de dependência...

```
@SpringBootTest
class UsuarioValidatorTest {

    @Autowired
    private UsuarioValidator validator;

    @Rule
    public ExpectedException thrown = ExpectedException.none();
}
```

Estou tentando testar essa parte do processo... mas tenho um erro. Veja meu método de teste implementado:

```
    @Test
    void insereComApelidoVazioTest() {
        thrown.expect(BadRequestException.class);
        thrown.expectMessage("O usuário precisa de um apelido");
        model = new CriaUsuarioDto();
        model.apelido = "";
        model.senha = "123123";
        validator.isNaoPodeIncluir(model);
    }
```

A mensagem  de erro que aparece em meu console, é referente ao meu isparo de exceção:

```
com.aimbra.dominio.exceptions.BadRequestException: O usuário precisa de um apelido

    at com.aimbra.seguranca.validators.UsuarioValidator.isNaoPodeIncluir(UsuarioValidator.java:25)
    at com.aimbra.seguranca.validators.UsuarioValidatorTest.insereComApelidoVazioTest(UsuarioValidatorTest.java:42)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
    at org.junit.platform.commons.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:675)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.MethodInvocation.proceed(MethodInvocation.java:60)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$ValidatingInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:125)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.intercept(TimeoutExtension.java:132)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptTestableMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:124)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptTestMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:74)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker$ReflectiveInterceptorCall.lambda$ofVoidMethod$0(ExecutableInvoker.java:115)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.lambda$invoke$0(ExecutableInvoker.java:105)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$InterceptedInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:104)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:62)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.chainAndInvoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:43)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.invoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:35)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.invoke(ExecutableInvoker.java:104)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.invoke(ExecutableInvoker.java:98)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestMethod$6(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:202)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.invokeTestMethod(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:198)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:135)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:69)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:135)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:125)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:135)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:123)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:122)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:80)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1507)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:125)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:135)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:123)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:122)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:80)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1507)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:125)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:135)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:123)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:122)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:80)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.submit(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:32)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:57)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:51)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:229)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.lambda$execute$6(DefaultLauncher.java:197)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.withInterceptedStreams(DefaultLauncher.java:211)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:191)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:128)
    at com.intellij.junit5.JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.java:69)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:47)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
```

Como fazer este teste passar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A biblioteca de testes JUnit 5 oferece muitos recursos para trablhar com TDD. Um dos métodos presentes se encontra o `Assertions`.

[Neste link](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/5.0.1/api/org/junit/jupiter/api/Assertions.html) pode-se encontrar os métodos presentes em `Assertions`.

Para testar um código que retorna uma exception, é simples... vide o exemplo abaixo:

```
@Test
    void invalidLengthThrownTest() {
        value = "Hello";
        String messageError = "The text is invalid length. You need of the field between 2 to 10 characteres";
        String message = Assertions.assertThrows(BadRequestException.class, () -> {
            validation.invalidLength(value, 2, 10, messageError);
        }).getMessage();
        assertEquals(messageError, message);
    }
```

Basta simplesmente invocar o método, e o primeiro parâmetro irá especificar a classe de excessão que esta vai chamar. O segundo parâmetro é uma callback que chamará o método que precisamente espera-se que ele emita um BadRequestException. A cunho de melhora na resposta, eu retorno a mensagem emitida pela exception para tratar no assertEquals.